# How to delete temporary folders when uninstall application

Tags: visual-studio, wix

When I uninstall my application then some temporary folders still there into windows volume directory or in installation directory.These temp folders created  when my application(exe) run. I want to delete all temp folders or files. Can any one please suggest how I achieve that. I have tried Custom Action to delete folders but does not got any success. Below is my code:

```
<product>
<Binary Id="CommandPrompt" SourceFile="C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" />
  <CustomAction Id="DeleteFolder" BinaryKey="CommandPrompt" 
              ExeCommand='cmd /c rmdir /S /Q "[WINDOWSVOLUME]"' 
              Execute="immediate" Return="check" />
  <CustomAction Id="DeleteFolder" BinaryKey="CommandPrompt" 
              ExeCommand='cmd /c rmdir /S /Q "[INSTALLDIR]"' 
              Execute="immediate" Return="check" />

</product>

<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="MyProgram" />
    </Directory>
    <Directory Id="WINDOWSVOLUME" >
        <Directory Id="ANOTHERLOCATION" Name="MyNewDir">

        </Directory>
    </Directory>
      </Directory>
</Directory>

<SetDirectory Id="WINDOWSVOLUME" Value="[WindowsVolume]" />

<Feature Id="DefaultFeature" Level="1">
  <Component Directory="INSTALLDIR">
    <File Id="ApplicationFile1" Source="C:\Users\user\Desktop\myprogram.exe" />
  </Component>
  <Component Directory="MyNewDir">
    <File Id="ApplicationFile2" Source="C:\Users\user\Desktop\InstallerFiles_13_4_9_3\myprogramLauncher.jar" />
  </Component>
</Feature>
```

Can anyone please provide me any solution.

Answer (score 0):

That's what the WiX RemoveFile element is for.

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/removefile.html

If you know what the files are called you'd use a wildcard in the Name.